# Cannot reinstall Lion on old iMac because "this item is temporarily unavailable"

Tags: macos, osx-lion, reinstall, imac

I need to reinstall the OS on my iMac. The original restore disk was deleted, so the restore system thingy was downloaded from Apple.

I tried to do reinstall OSX, but it appears Lion is no longer on the app store. What should I do?

Comment: http://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT4718

Comment: I think this is happening because you never purchased Lion using that Apple ID. Did you use someone else's?